# I'm creating an app using dart for a list view of images

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Basically, I'm learning Dart for the first time. I'm still learning the syntax and everything.
I have created four files
1.main dart
2.app dart
3.image_list dart
4.image_model dart
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRUp3.png)

I am pasting the code here please can anyone help me.
Thank you in advance.
Image_model

```
class ImageModel {
  int id;
  String url;
  String title;
  ImageModel(this.id, this.url, this.title);

  ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
    :id = parsedJson['id'],
    url = parsedJson['url'],
    title = parsedJson['title'];  
}
```

Image_list

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/image_model.dart';

class ImageList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ImageModel> images;

  ImageList(this.images);

  Widget build(context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
          return Text(images[index].url);
        },
      );
  }
}
```

some part of app dart

```
class AppState extends State<App> {
  int counter = 0;
  List<ImageModel> images = [];

  void fetchImage() async {
    counter++;
    String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/$counter";
    var response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url));
    var image_model = ImageModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));

    setState(() {
      images.add(image_model);
    });
  }
```

Comment: seems like the id from the api response is null/empty, could you double check the response?

Answer (score 1):

The data coming in parsedJson variable might have Id null or not an int. can you check.

Comment: Hey i tried using "late" beside id and title but the same error is repeating

Comment: can you add where you are calling fetchImage function because fetchImage method is an async method you have to call it in FutureBuilder or something like that or else it always  will be null

Comment: can i ping you some where so that i can share my code